# Problem installing steam in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, package-management, software-installation, steam

I have just install steam from the terminal as you can see:

[image: image 1]

But when I try to open steam as you can see:

[image: image 2]

And finally, if I continue with it I get this:

[image: image 3]

I have already install the Canonical packages from software update, I have tried use the `.deb` file from steam website but it also didn't work, it always shows me the same. Also, if I click on steam icon it shows me the same image 3.

So, what should I do?

Comment: Error: "You are missiing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6"

Comment: oh, i have just understand, i finally solved (i'm a noob user with linux terminal haha)

Comment: in the terminal write:
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386

Comment: and then open steam

Comment: and continue with the installation

Comment: Please do not post text outputs as image, but copy/paste them into your text.

Answer (score -1):

If you're getting

`Error: "You are missiing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run: libc.so.6"`

try running:

`sudo apt-get install libc6-i386`

Comment: That alone won't help. Apt already tries to install that package but fails to do so. OP needs to enable the `i386` foreign architecture first. See my linked question. -1

Comment: @DavidFoerster I mean it did work OP already put the solution to his problem. so stop with your down-voting and read the full post